# How to install socialite in laravel 5.7 using composer?

Tags: composer-php, laravel-5.7, laravel-socialite

I'm trying to install socialite in laravel 5.7. But it seems that the installer package not found. Here is how it looks:

```
composer require laravel/socialite
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
The "http://packagist.org/p/paragonie/random_compat%24db1b5c1b43ef534aed7fe377b7d6e9ada59ee25deed500ba426fd9e421116aa3.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! 
http://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
```

I've tried using `composer require laravel/socialite` and `composer require laravel/socialite "^3.2.0"` but get the same problem.

Comment: Please share more details - to me, this looks like a networking issue

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the solution from [here](https://www.makoajacobsen.com/2014/09/12/composer-http-request-failed/)

So what I do is adding this lines to `composer.json` file

```
"repositories": [
{
    "packagist": false
},
{
    "type": "composer",
    "url": "https://packagist.org/"
}
],
```

As you can see composer requires `https` while laravel use `http` by default.

Comment: You should probably update your composer instead (`composer self-update`).

Answer (score -1):

"^3.2.0" this is for laravel 5.6 for laravel 5.7 frame work try this

```
composer require laravel/socialite "4.0"
```

Comment: Please share more details. How does this resolve the networking problems?